# Swift - get user password through dialog

Tags: swift, macos, root

I am creating an application with Xcode and I need to use the users password to perform root tasks. My problem is that without creating a pipe that uses sudo like `shell("echo",prompt("Enter Password"),"| sudo -S do_root_thing")` which is very insecure (shell and prompt are pre-defined). I know some programs display an alert message such as this:

[image: Username/Password dialog]

Is there a secure way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a privileged helper tool, install it using `SMJobBless`, and communicate with it via XPC.

A good example to help you get started is [EvenBetterAuthorizationSample.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

If you want an easier Swift-based solution, I have made a library named [CSAuthSample](https://github.com/CharlesJS/CSAuthSample) which attempts to be as easy-to-use as possible while also providing some additional features. *DISCLAIMER:* I am the author of this library.

Comment: There is very little documentation of SMJobBless, and I have no idea what it is

Comment: @Namo You're right; I actually wrote a Swift-based library myself a while ago to solve this problem, so I'll add a link. Hopefully SO does not consider it spam :-/